# Why is my header overlapping my navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a basic blog and my header keeps extending up behind my navbar. The navbar has a fixed position and a z-index that is higher than the header. I can't figure out why the top of the header/banner image is extending behind the navbar. I am including a picture of the issue highlighted in FF dev tools and you can see my site directly [here](http://www.joelbitar.space/) if you'd like. Any help/input greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: you must show **what you have done** till yet. \

Comment: Position fixed element will not take any space, so the next element i.e: your banner will always start from the "top:0" and "left:0", and you have to adjust your banner images using margins only.

Comment: Shiva, thanks for helping me understand this. Greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: as shiva said fixed doesnt take any space, so just add some more margin.

```
header {
    margin: 89px 0 0;  // update margin
}
```

And update your media screen

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
header {
margin: 80px 0 0;
}
}
```

Comment: That put the header all the way behind the navbar :P

Comment: With the position relative header is on top of the navigation, so z-index doesnt matter at that point. I removed the position, just adjust the margin and it will look as you wanted. Take a look here http://prntscr.com/bgjqu9

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed to understand. Appreciate that so much

Comment: No problem, just play a little bit more with the developer tool. Really easy way to test the design part of the website.

Comment: I was completely unaware that a fixed position section of the page does not take up any space. Great to know moving forward!